# Different validating actions in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to implement simple CMS. I have `Page` class instances of which I want to add to the database and also to edit them. 
The `UrlName` in the `Page` should be unique so I made custom validator, though, while editing I cannot submit form without changing `UrlName` to an unexisting one. How can I pass extra data to my `VerifyUrl` or maybe there is another way to solve this problem?

```
public class Page : IUpdatable<Page>
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Url)]
    [Remote(action: "VerifyUrl", controller: "Pages")]
    public string UrlName { get; set; }
}
```

This is my validating method in `PagesController`

```
public JsonResult VerifyUrl(string UrlName)   
{
    if (!db.Pages.Any(x => x.UrlName.Equals(UrlName)) )
         return Json(data: true);
    return Json(data: "This Url is already in use");
}
```

And this is in my View

```
<input asp-for="UrlName" class="form-control" />
<span asp-validation-for="UrlName" class="text-danger" />
```

Comment: please don't use [tag:asp.net-mvc] for for ASP.NET Core, use [tag:asp.net-core-mvc]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify 'This URL is already in use' in Remote ErrorMessage and in your Action Mehtod, return false in Json if provided URL is already is Use.

**Model class**

```
[DisplayName("URL")]
   [Required]
   [Remote("Validate", "Home", HttpMethod = "Post", ErrorMessage = "This URL already exists")]
   public string URL { get; set; }
```

**In your controller**

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Validate(string URL)
    {
       //Do validation here from DataBas
        //if URL already exist, return false, else true;

            return Json(false);

    }
```

<kbd>***[Working Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uv2Qch)***</kbd>

To pass additional information to your controller method, you can specify an Additional Field in Remote Attribute as:

```
     [DisplayName("User name")]
     [Required]
      public string UserName { get; set; }

      [DisplayName("URL")]
      [Required]
      [Remote("Validate", "Home", HttpMethod = "Post",AdditionalFields="UserName", ErrorMessage = "This URL and Username should not be same")]
     public string URL { get; set; }
```

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Validate(string URL, string UserName)
    {
        if(URL == UserName)
            return Json(false);
        else
            return Json(true);

    }
```

***<kbd>[Woking Demo for additional field](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GowXuA)</kbd>***

Comment: You just did, what I did. I provided all this code in my question. It works perfectly with adding instances to the db. My problem is validating Url when I edit an existing instance

Comment: In first example, i just showed you that how to use Error Message in Remote Attribute. Second example exhibits 'How can I pass extra data to my `VerifyUrl`'

Comment: Thank you , when I commented, there was no info about how to pass extra data. This really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you allow the user to change the URL when editing a post? If not I would create separate view models, one for "New Post" and one for "Edit Post".

The New Post View Model can call the validation method. And when editing, as long as you don't allow the user to change the URL in the UI, you won't need to revalidate it.